# Visual Basic .net Adding external drivers in project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, driver

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I am currently using VB .NET building application.

I have a question about "How can I add the external drivers in the VB.NET project, so people doesn't manually install to run the application "

For example, the current application is using CMW 500 drivers to run application.

For running application, people manually download the drivers from the company website to install drivers.

I am assuming that I can add the all drivers to the VB.NET project. ( Like adding jar files for java project at eclipse project)

I am not really sure how to add the all drivers in my VB.NET project.

Does anybody know how to add the all drivers in VB.NET project ?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA?  Please fix your tags.

Comment: You cannot reasonable bundle 3rd party drivers with your installer, they have a heavy Windows version dependency and  they get updated all the time and the manufacturer isn't going to tell you about it.  Or provide you with the merge files you need to integrate their installer with yours.  Nor do you want to take care of the support call when something goes wrong.  Just make it a prerequisite for your app, help the user find the correct download in your readme.txt